# How to access src attribute within Angular directive when using ng-src

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following HTML (inside a gsp):

```
<img ng-src="${resource(dir: '')}/images/stores/closeBTN.svg" />
```

I want to use Modernizr to detect whether or not SVG is supported, and switch the image to a png if it's not. I've adapted this directive: https://github.com/tinacious/angular-svg-png

```
angular.module('svgPng', [])
  .directive('img', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        if ( typeof Modernizr !== 'undefined' && !Modernizr.svg ) {
          elem.attr('src', attrs.src.replace('.svg', '.png'));
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

The problem is that attrs.src is undefined, so the replace doesn't work. I know that ng-src should populate the src, so do I need to force a digest loop or something to make src defined?

Comment: What does the syntax `${resource(dir: '')}` mean?

Comment: It's a Grails plugin that will correctly generate links to static resources. Just inserts a path there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it too early before the digest cycle, which processes `ng-src` and adds src attribute. So let the digest cycle happen, you can make sure of it by placing this in `$timeout` or use `setTimeout`.

```
 .directive('img', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        if ( typeof Modernizr !== 'undefined' && !Modernizr.svg ) {
         $timeout(function(){
            elem.attr('src', attrs.src.replace('.svg', '.png'));
         }, false);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Or a better bet would be t do the replacement too early before `ngSrc` has a chance to even process it. Use the compile function to replace the extension in ng-src attribute's value, and also this prevent both the images to be loaded as it would happen in the previous case (one with .svg and one with .png).

```
 .directive('img', function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          compile: function (elem, attrs) {
            if ( typeof Modernizr !== 'undefined' && !Modernizr.svg ) {
               attrs.$set('ngSrc', attrs.ngSrc.replace('.svg', '.png'));
            }
          }
      };
 });
```

Comment: wouldn't be possible, though rare, that the code you wrapped in a $timeout could execute before a digest cycle completes and the `src` attr is added?

Comment: @user2943490 Another issue with this approach could be that repalcement since it happens late both the images will be downloaded and possibility of a flicker also. So i have added another way to perform the replacement too early before ng-src can even process it.

Comment: @HellaMedusa Check out my second option

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement it.